# cypress-file-upload attachFile is not a function

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to test my file uploading function using Cypress-file-upload but I hurt myself against `.attachFile is not a function`

[image]

I tried two solutions and I still can't make it works :

```
// 1st one, "find file input" works

  it('find file input', () => {
    cy.get('input[type="file"')
  })
  
  const fileName = 'french_tweets_split.csv';
  it('Testing csv uploading', () => {
    cy.fixture(fileName, 'binary')
      .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
      .then(fileContent => {
        cy.get("input[type='file']").attachFile({ fileContent, fileName, mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', encoding:'utf8' })
    })
  })
```

```
// 2nd one, "find file input" works
  it('find file input', () => {
    cy.get('input[type="file"')
  })
  
  it('Testing csv uploading', () => {
    cy.fixture('french_tweets_split.csv').then(fileContent => {
        cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile({
            fileContent: fileContent.toString(),
            fileName: 'french_tweets_split.csv',
            mimeType: 'text/csv'
        })
    })
  })
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try looking if you had made all the necessary configurations listed on this page and update it to the latest version. It works for me very well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to import the package:

**support/index.js**

```js
import 'cypress-file-upload';
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to Install **cypress-file-upload** dev dependency first:

```
npm i cypress-file-upload --save-dev
```

Then import it in **cypress/support/index.js**

```
import 'cypress-file-upload'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am working with TypeScript. I had to import it in `support/index.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps-

1. Install "**npm i cypress-file-upload --save-dev**"
2. In **support/index.js** and **support/commands.js** add > **import 'cypress-file-upload';**
3. Use the below code snippet

> cy.fixture('video.mp4')
> .then(fileContent => {
> cy.get('.qq-uploader-selector > input').attachFile({
> fileContent,
> fileName: 'video.mp4',
> mimeType: 'video/mp4',
> encoding: 'utf8'
> })
> })

NOTE: Use ".attachFile" along with get method instead of ".upload" to avoid "cy.get(...).upload is not a function"